# Discrepancy in Facebook Graph API Documentation Regarding Page Likes (Incoming vs Outgoing)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking at the Facebook Graph API documentation and noticed something odd, or maybe I'm misunderstanding something.

This page here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/page/likes describes `/{page-id}/likes` as returning "The Pages that this Page Likes"

However, this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/object/likes (which seems to be describing the same endpoint if a `{page-id}` is passed in for `{object-id}` is saying that it returns "An array of User or Page objects representing the people or Pages that liked the object".

The first link says `/{page-id}/likes` will return outgoing likes for a page, whereas the second link suggests the same endpoint will return incoming likes. Testing it out in the Graph Explorer indicates that the 2nd link is true, which makes me wonder how I can access the outgoing likes described by the first link, as that is what I am interested in.

Am I misunderstanding something here? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to know how many users like the page - that's in the `fan_count` field these days. Documentation is not up to date in this regard; file a documentation bug and ask them to fix it. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the tip, I submitted it as a potential documentation bug. `fan_count` is useful, but I'm looking explicitly for lists of likes - both incoming and outgoing

Comment: There is no list of all users that like a page available via API.

Comment: @CBroe isn't this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/object/likes a list of all users that like a page?

Comment: No, it's not - because of what you already quoted from the documentation.

Comment: Most of what the documentation for `/object/likes` says, does not actually apply when the object is a page. It was for example never possible to publish a like of a page using the API, that has always needed the official Like buttons.

Comment: @CBroe gotcha. I think I miswrote my original question, it seems like the documentation for the first link I listed is correct, not the second.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145776/discussion-between-patrick-devivo-and-cbroe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the Facebook documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/638061899718019/